# Не работает показ использованной памяти vue.js + socket.io

Tags: vue.js, websocket, socket.io

По идее должны выводиться значения использованной памяти, но не выводятся.

App.vue

```
<template>
      <div id="app">
        <strong>Server Stats</strong><br>
        RSS: <span id='rss'>{{rss}}</span><br/>
        Heap total: <span id='heapTotal'>{{heapTotal}}</span><br>
        Heap used: <span id='heapUsed'>{{heapUsed}}</span><br>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() {
      return {
        heapUsed: '',
        heapTotal:'',
        rss:''
      }
    }
  }
</script>    
<style>
</style>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
  debug: false,
  connection: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));


new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('../..')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  socket.on('new message', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      socket.emit(JSON.stringify(process.memoryUsage()));
    },100);
  });
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test_simple",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-socket.io": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.6.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.6.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.6.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Можете пояснить подобные записи `:v-model="..."`, зачем применяется биндинг к директиве, да еще повесили на `span`? Директива применяется к элементу ввода.

Comment: Очень верное замечание, исправил.